# Ethereum resources to build a decentralized application

Tags: dapps

I was searching the dApp [Decentralized application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_application)
 topic and many resources recommend Ethereum to build a dapp. What I plan to do is to build a [decentralized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_application) mobile app with a distributed database. I have a Qt/QML code that I like to base my app on it but python/kivy and react native are also options. I have seen Ethereum clients but don't know whether i have to use them to build the network or something else. Please provide some resources (Especially related books) for those who want to build a network on top of Ethereum.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to start playing with javascript clien libraries, with [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) installed in your browser, like:

- [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)
- [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/)

Try to develop a javascript application, with no backend, except Ethereum Smart Contracts, that you can easily start developing in [Remix online IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/)

After that, you can start playing with more complex development environment like [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/) or [Oppenzeppelin SDK](https://openzeppelin.com/sdk/), and trying [mobile integrations of Metamask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile).

You will find lots of information in [Ethereum documentation website](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/) and also very useful help for not reinventing the wheel in [Openzeppelin website](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of book I'd recommend:

- ["Mastering Ethereum"](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook) by Andreas Antonopoulos.
- ["Ethereum for Web Developers"](https://github.com/Apress/ethereum-for-web-developers) by Santiago Palladino.