# Create new UI for deployed contract with remix?

Tags: remix, metamask, gui

Is there any way to create new UI for a contracted deployed with Remix?

I know, I can use remix and Metamask to deploy contracts to real ethereum networks (Main, Rinkeby,...) and remix provides us a simple ui to interact with the deployed contracts.

But is there a way to create a new UI using frameworks (like react.js) for a deployed contract?

If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a web3 client library to interact with the Smart Contract, from the client app.

I recommend you to start playing with javascript clien libraries, with [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) installed in your browser, like:

- [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)
- [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/)

Try to develop a javascript application, with no backend, except Ethereum Smart Contracts, that you can easily start developing in [Remix online IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/)

After that, you can start playing with more complex development environment like [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/) or [Oppenzeppelin SDK](https://openzeppelin.com/sdk/), and trying [mobile integrations of Metamask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile).

You will find lots of information in [Ethereum documentation website](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/) and also very useful help for not reinventing the wheel in [Openzeppelin website](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/).

From this post:
[Resources to build a dApp on top of Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91348/resources-to-build-a-dapp-on-top-of-ethereum/91353#91353)